# Crystal Report not passing parameters to subreport

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a configurable win forms app in which I can set how much times a subreport can be inserted into main report like this:

Config page: (order of importing subreports)

SubRep1
SubRep1
SubRep1
SubRep3
SubRep3
SubRep2
SubRep2
SubRep2

So, in my main report I will import/insert 3 times subreport 1, 2 times subreport 2 and 3 times subreport 2. Each subreport has a one parameter and I set through code a value, but it only appears on the first instance of the report...

So, like this:

SubRep1 (has a parameter)
SubRep1
SubRep1
SubRep3 (has a parameter)
SubRep3
SubRep2 (has a parameter)
SubRep2
SubRep2

The problem is that I need to have a parameter for each one!
My code...

```
SetMainReportParameters(reportParameterList);

                for (int i = 0; i < rlc.ReportLayout.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (rlc.ReportLayout[i].SubreportName == "SectionReportTest1.rpt")
                    {
                        SetSectionOneReportParameters(reportParameterList);
                    }
                    if (rlc.ReportLayout[i].SubreportName == "SectionReportTest2.rpt")
                    {
                        SetSectionTwoReportParameters(reportParameterList);
                    }
                    if (rlc.ReportLayout[i].SubreportName == "SectionReportTest3.rpt")
                    {
                        SetSectionThreeReportParameters(reportParameterList);
                    }
                }
```

and when passing...

```
//list of every parameter (main and subreports)
                foreach (var current in reportParameterList)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(current.SubreportName))
                    {
                        document.SetParameterValue(current.Name, current.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.SetParameterValue(current.Name, current.Value, current.SubreportName);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `*.rpt` file of the main report you need to add links between the subreports and the main report and pass the parameters values in there. Should be available in the context menu of the subreport object in the template.